# Error en Android Studio accediendo a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero crear una app en android studio con base de datos xammp y me sale error de warning, no se que hice mal

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $confirpass= $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true; 

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line
>   4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line 10
>   {"success":true}

Comment: Nos puedes pegar un trozo de tu código donde te está fallando a la hora de acceder a esos php y en la calse java en android studio para poder ayudarte mejor, asi es imposible XD

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con Android, sino con php

Comment: No tiene por que, ahi dice que no encuentra el index "name", lo recoge por post y perfectamente puede estar enviandolo por get y no haberse dado cuenta, y para eso necesito ver como envía esos parámetros

Comment: ¿Mencionas Android Studio porque estás enviando una petición desde Android al servidor? Los `Undefined index` hacen pensar que los datos no se están enviando correctamente, conviene que [edites tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/166944/edit) poniendo el código que hace la petición al servidor (Java/Android, supongo), porque es evidente que los valores a insertar, que recoges por `POST` no están llegando y por tanto la consulta fallará.

Comment: La indicación NOTICE es por que no encuentra las variables POST, checa que cuando pases los parametros, los estes recibiendo con el mismo nombre que lo mandaste, o bien que no los estes mandando por GET en vez de POST.

Puedes subir el código del formulario para porderte ayudar más

Answer (score 2):

### Notice: Undefined variable

Referente a lo que dice [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.basics.php)

> Confiar en el valor predeterminado de una variable no inicializada es problemático en el caso de incluir un archivo en otro que usa el mismo nombre de variable. También es un gran [riesgo de seguridad](http://php.net/manual/es/security.globals.php) con register_globals activado. El error de nivel [E_NOTICE](http://www.php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-notice) se emite en caso de trabajar con variables no inicializadas, pero no en el caso de agregar elementos a la matriz no inicializada. La función [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) se puede usar para detectar si una variable ya se ha inicializado. Además, y más ideal es la solución de [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) ya que no genera un mensaje de advertencia o error si la variable no se inicializa.

En la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

> No se genera una advertencia si la variable no existe. Esto significa que empty() es esencialmente el equivalente conciso de !isset($var) || $var == false.

Esto significa que puede usar solo `empty()` para determinar si la variable está configurada, y además verifica la variable contra lo siguiente, `0, "", null`.

Ejemplo:

```
$o = [];
@$var = ["",0,null,1,2,3,$foo,$o['myIndex']];
array_walk($var, function($v) {
    echo (!isset($v) || $v == false) ? 'true ' : 'false';
    echo ' ' . (empty($v) ? 'true' : 'false');
    echo "\n";
});
```

Pruebe el fragmento de arriba en [3v4l.org online PHP editor](https://3v4l.org/5Wvgj)

Aunque PHP no requiere una declaración de variables, sí lo recomienda para evitar algunas vulnerabilidades de seguridad o errores donde uno olvidará dar un valor a una variable que se utilizará más adelante en el script. Lo que hace PHP en el caso de las variables no declaradas es emitir un error de nivel muy bajo, `E_NOTICE`, uno que ni siquiera se informa de manera predeterminada, pero el Manual [aconseja permitirlo](http://www.php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) durante el desarrollo.

Maneras de lidiar con el problema:

1. Recomendada: Declare sus variables, por ejemplo, cuando intente agregar una cadena a una variable indefinida. O use `isset()` / `!empty()` para verificar si están declarados antes de hacer referencia a ellos, como en:

   ```
   //Inicializando la variable
   $value = ""; //Valor de inicialización; Ejemplos
                //"" Cuando quiera agregar cosas más tarde
                //0  Cuando quiera agregar números después
   //isset()
   $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
   //empty()
   $value = !empty($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
   ```

   Esto se ha vuelto mucho más limpio a partir de PHP 7.0, ahora puedes usar [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary):

   ```
   // Null coalesce operator - No es necesario inicializar explícitamente la variable.
   $value = $_POST['value'] ?? '';
   ```
2. Establezca un [controlador de error personalizado](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php) para E_NOTICE y redirija los mensajes fuera del resultado estándar (tal vez a un archivo de registro):

   ```
   set_error_handler('myHandlerForMinorErrors', E_NOTICE | E_STRICT)
   ```
3. Desactivar E_NOTICE de informes. Una forma rápida de excluir solo `E_NOTICE` es:

   ```
   error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE )
   ```
4. Suprime el error con el [operador @](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

**Nota:** Se recomienda encarecidamente implementar solo el punto 1.

### Notice: Undefined index / Undefined offset

Este aviso aparece cuando usted (o PHP) intenta acceder a un índice indefinido de una matriz.

Maneras de lidiar con el problema:

1. Verifique si el índice existe antes de acceder a él. Para esto puedes usar [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) o [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php):

   ```
   //isset()
   $value = isset($array['my_index']) ? $array['my_index'] : '';
   //array_key_exists()
   $value = array_key_exists('my_index', $array) ? $array['my_index'] : '';
   ```
2. La función [list()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php) puede generar esto cuando intenta acceder a un índice de matriz que no existe:

   ```
   list($a, $b) = array(0 => 'a');
   // o
   list($one, $two) = explode(',', 'test string');
   ```

Se utilizan dos variables para acceder a dos elementos de matriz, sin embargo, solo hay un elemento de matriz, índice 0, por lo que generará:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

## Variable $_POST / $_GET / $_SESSION

Los avisos anteriores aparecen a menudo cuando se trabaja con $_POST, $_GET o $ _SESSION. Para $_POST y $_GET solo tiene que verificar si el índice existe o no antes de usarlo. Para $_SESSION, debe asegurarse de que la sesión haya comenzado con [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) y que el índice también exista.

También tenga en cuenta que las 3 variables son [superglobales](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php). Esto significa que deben escribirse en mayúsculas.

Relacionado:

- Notice: [Undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12778634#12778634) (Inglés)
- Notice: [Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836) (Inglés)

Esta respuesta fue tomada y traducida de [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)